# azure file storage crashed. cloudFile.DownloadText returns long empty string like "\0\0\0\0\0\0"

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

We have file storage account to store files for our customers.
But files crash often. It seems content was replaced with empty string like "\0\0\0\0\0\0".

Corrupted file is normally found a few days (or a few months) later.

`cloudFile.DownloadText returns string like "\0\0\0\0\0\0".`

Here is an example file '100days.slider' at http://www.jssor.com/jssordev/problems*

We save file to azure file storage in the following 3 ways,

1. Upload text `cloudFile.UploadText(content, Encoding.UTF8);`
2. Upload from another cloud file `dstCloudFile.UploadFromStream(srcCloudFile.OpenRead());`
3. Upload from user posted file `cloudFile.UploadFromStream(httpPostedFile.InputStream);`

Does anyone know what's happening?

Check the 'full-width-slider.slider' at http://www.jssor.com/danishrabbani*
This is a new corrupted file today (2016-10-24).

User went through 2 steps as below, and problem found at the 2nd step.

1. [OK] User edited the file at http://www.jssor.com/danishrabbani/full-width-slider.slider/=edit, it means it read the file correctly.
2. [Issue] And then user go to http://www.jssor.com/danishrabbani/full-width-slider.slider/=preview from the previous page.

Both steps read the same file, so the problem may be caused by the 2nd read.
Assuming that user saved data between step 1 and step 2, then the problem should be caused by `cloudFile.UploadText(content, Encoding.UTF8);`.

**Edit 2016-10-26**

Today's new empty file 'different-size-photo-slider-with-text.slider' found here http://www.jssor.com/mfleury*

We investigated on file upload in both way of `UploadText` and `UploadFromStream`, no exception raised. I think the problem is at azure file storage server side or the file storage SDK library.

**Edit 2016-10-27**

Today's new empty file 'different-size-photo-slider.slider' here http://www.jssor.com/zubairqd*

**Edit 2016-11-08**

No exception raised, file upload always succeeded.

User normally saves a copy of our demo to start with, `dstCloudFile.UploadFromStream(srcCloudFile.OpenRead());`

After that, user edits file in slider maker, and then save the file,
`cloudFile.UploadText(content, Encoding.UTF8);`

We traced reads of corrupted file, most of the time, it happens with firefox (version 49) on X64 or WOW64 system. So the problem might be caused by `cloudFile.UploadText(content, Encoding.UTF8);`.

Also, it happened with my win7 (x86) system about 1 year ago, there is no lzw compression at that time.

To save file from slider maker, it sends lzw compressed data to our server, and then uncompress, and then `cloudFile.UploadText` to file storage. We did check to see if the first 2 characters are "\0\0", but we didn't find any text like that.

Comment: Can you share how files are uploaded? Also can you share the file before it is being uploaded?

Comment: Could you describe how the code crashed? It would be best if you could share the exception.

Comment: I don't know if the crash is caused by writing or reading operation, may be  reading.

Comment: Please *edit your question* with more detail - don't create such a lengthy list of comments. All these comments you added should be deleted, with content moved into your question.

Comment: Couple of clarification questions: In any of these cases, is there a chance the source file that you are uploading is in progress of being copied from elsewhere? Also, how are you handling exceptions from upload file calls if they have failed?

Comment: The upload succeeded, there is no exception, and I will investigate more on this point. The user registered yesterday, he is new to our system. I think he used 'save as' command to save our demo to his own workspace. As he opened the slider maker successfully, so, the first write and the first read is OK. I am sure that the problem caused by subsequent operation (maybe ```UploadText``` or read).